# When and with which parameters does strongSwan select a connection?

Tags: ipsec, strongswan

StrongSwan (as responder) selects a configured connection (conn section in `ipsec.conf`) for each incoming initiator key exchange intent.

At which times does strongSwan pick a connection configuration? Does it narrow possible connections one-by-one based on the knowledge gathered so far?

E.g. in an IKEv2-exchange, the first packet does not contain the identifier (“rightid”) yet, but connections with `keyexchange=ikev1` are out of the question already.

The first response (in case no cookies are involved) should already indicate the algorithms selected for the IKE SA, so *some* connection has to be selected. How could strongSwan possibly do this at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could strongSwan possibly do this at that point?

A preliminary configuration is selected based on the IP addresses (*left|right*) and the IKE version. The best match (or the first if multiple configurations match equally well) is used until the identities in the IKE_AUTH exchange are available.

Using the identities a switch to a different connection will occur based on the values in *left|rightid* (and again the IKE version). All matching connections are candidates (best match first) that might later be switched to e.g. based on the authentication rounds and constraints like *rightca* or *rightgroups*.

Comment: That is really interesting information! – Is this documented somewhere? How often can this configuration switching/narrowing happen? Does it really switch at least once (or only narrow)? (Might I end up with an undesired _ike_ cipher this way!?) Is there a list of which parameters will be used for matching? (You need to know them all for proper config-writing...)

Comment: There will always be a lookup based on the identities, but that could, of course, result in the same config. After each authentication round is finished there could be another switch. There are some limitations (e.g. switching based on EAP identities is currently not possible). And yes, the selected IKE proposal might be different than defined in the final configuration (the order is important if multiple configs match the IPs). Most considered parameters should be clear based on the documentation in the man/wiki page (otherwise check the example configs or do some specific tests yourself).

Comment: Rep-points dealt. But as you might imagine: it still leaves many questions open. – How can be something so crucial not be clearly outlined in the documentation? I read the wiki and man-pages up and down. – I would even go so far and say that this connection switching is a design bug in strongSwan: it should only narrow down on further possible connections and not jump to an incompatible one. – And the documentation should say: “leave the _ike_ ciphers the same on all your connections or you might exclude a perfect match later on, because <blablabla>”

Comment: I guess it usually "just works" so there wasn't much need to explicitly document it. Not sure what you mean with "jump to an incompatible one" but to clarify, you can't "exclude" a connection via IKE ciphers as they are not considered when looking up the initial connection. However, this could lead to the selection of a config (based on the IPs) that is not compatible with a specific client's IKE proposal (but a later config that matches equally well might be).

Comment: Haven’t tried it but: server is `conn a → ike=a1, rightid=1` and `conn b → ike=b2, rightid=2`. Now a client comes with `ike=a1,b2, leftid=2`. – If I understood you right, server will select `conn a` first, go with ike-cipher a1, then jump to `conn b` _and leave a1_ even though it is not allowed there!

Comment: Correct, that's exactly the situation I was referring to. And since IKE proposals are currently not compared it wouldn't help for the client to configure `ike=b2`. Actually, it would result in a `NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN` error if `conn a` is selected (there won't be a switch to `conn b` based on the proposal mismatch).

Comment: Could you point me to the source code where that searching/matching is done? (only necessary if it’s readable... ;-)

Comment: The initial IKE config is selected in [backend_manager.c](https://git.strongswan.org/?p=strongswan.git;a=blob;f=src/libcharon/config/backend_manager.c;hb=HEAD#l132) as is the list of configs based on the identities [further down in the file](https://git.strongswan.org/?p=strongswan.git;a=blob;f=src/libcharon/config/backend_manager.c;hb=HEAD#l324). Switching between the latter will happen in [ike_auth.c](https://git.strongswan.org/?p=strongswan.git;a=blob;f=src/libcharon/sa/ikev2/tasks/ike_auth.c;hb=HEAD#l321).